# Do Animals breed?

Tags: banished

In Banished you can build pastures that hold either chicken, cows or sheep. If you have 2 or more of one of those animals, will they breed on their own, or is the only way to get more animals through the merchant?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Animals will reproduce, although they won't actually "breed". You can actually get away with only buying one animal from a trader, and your herd will grow anyway (although this is a little bit of a risk)

Comment: How are we differentiating breeding and reproducing?

Comment: I mean, you don't need two animals: one will reproduce by itself. Perhaps through mitosis.

Comment: Take heed of the risk of buying just 1 .... I bought 3 cattle. The count went up to 4. Then gradually down to 1 :o I thought I would have to wait a few more years for the trader to return, but luckily it started increasing again.